# What if I just dont visit the children of the queue_front node but just push them into the queue? Will it still be BFS?

Tags: c++, queue, stdvector, breadth-first-search

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-bfs-shortest-reach/problem
In this problem, I tried BFS by just (first approach) visiting the queue_front node and pushing its children into the queue and not visiting its children nodes instead of (second approach) visiting all its children and then pushing them into the queue.
In the first approach, the test cases failed, but in the second approach, it passed. But in both the cases I am using BFS. So why is it failing then. The code is below.In this code first approach is enabled which is failing some test cases in the above hackerrank problem. The second approach passes all the test cases. Please look at the bfs function. I am using adjacency list to implement graph. PLEASE HELP!! THANK YOU!!

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
vector<long> bfs(vector<vector<int>> &graph, int s,int n){
    queue<pair<int,long> > st;
    vector<bool> vis(n+1,0);
    st.push(make_pair(s,0));
    vector<long> cost(n+1,-1);
    cost[s] = 0;
    vis[s] = 1;
    while(!st.empty()){
        pair<int,long> node = st.front();
        st.pop();
        //I am visiting the queue_front element, enabling first approach
        vis[node.first] = 1;
        cost[node.first] = node.second;
        for(long i = 0;i<graph[node.first].size();i++){
            if(!vis[graph[node.first][i]])
            {
                st.push(make_pair(graph[node.first][i],long(node.second)+long(6)));
                //Below 2 lines are commented to disable the second approach
                //cost[graph[node.first][i]] = node.second + 6;
                //vis[graph[node.first][i]] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return cost;
}
int main(){
    int q;
    cin>>q;
    while(q--){
        int n,m;
        cin>>n>>m;
        vector<vector<int>> graph(n+1);
        for(long i = 0;i<m;i++){
            int u,v;
            cin>>u>>v;
            graph[u].push_back(v);
            graph[v].push_back(u);
        }
        int s;
        cin>>s;
        vector<long> cost(n+1,-1);
        cost = bfs(graph,s,n);
        cost.erase(cost.begin());
        cost.erase(cost.begin()+s-1);
        for(long i = 0;i<cost.size();i++){
            cout<<long(cost[i])<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've no idea but the second approach is not BFS. In BFS you visit a node when you pop it off the queue, not when you push it onto the queue.

Comment: but the problem statement is accepting the second approach and saying that it is a bfs question. Did you see the question?? Thank You!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visiting nodes when you pop them out of the queue will be same as dfs it will not ensure you shortest path.if you will visit nodes then push it into the queue it will give you the shortest path consider the case :

node 1 is connected to node 2 and node 2 with node3 and node3 with node1 in a cyclic form

we will use a queue<pair<int,int>> q;
first element of pair is the node and second element is distance to the node from start.

Case 1:
this is a cyclic graph with start node as 1 we want to find min distance from 1 to 3.we push 1 into queue.we will pop it out and push node 2 and 3 into the queue without visiting it.when we will pop out 2 then we visit 2 and push 3 so when we pop out 3 we will check it the popped node is equal to 3 and we store the min distance.so in this case our min distance is 2.which we have find out using depth traversal.

But the answer should be 1 as 1 is directly connected with 3.

case 2:we will visit the node before pushing it into queue

start node is 1 and push it.visit 2 and 3 and then push both into stack.when we will pop node 2 we check the adjacent elements and both 3 and 2 are visited.so we will pop 3 and check if it is destination node.so we will store the distance.so in this case dist[1] to dist[3]=0+1 which is 1.